# How can iterate in Dictionary in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I create a dictionary

```
    Dim ImageCollection As New Dictionary(Of ConvensionImages, Integer)
```

and I fill that

```
 For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim obj As New ConvensionImages
            obj.ImageID = dr("ID")
            obj.Name = dr("Name")
            obj.Description = dr("Description")
            obj.CategoryID = dr("CategoryID")
            obj.CategoryName = dr("CategoryName")
            obj.CategoryDescription = dr("CatDescription")
            obj.EventID = dr("EventID")
            obj.Image = dr("img")
            obj.DownloadImage = dr("DownLoadImg")
            ImageCollection.Add(obj, key)
            key = key + 1
```

now I want to search ImageID and key how can I do this

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Make `Integer` as key for your Dictionary:

```
Dim ImageCollection As New Dictionary(Of Integer, ConvensionImages)
```

Change `ImageCollection.Add(obj, key)` to `ImageCollection.Add(key, obj)`

And use this loop:

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, ConvensionImages) In ImageCollection
     Dim v1 As Integer = kvp.Key  
     Dim v2 As ConvensionImages = kvp.Value  
     'Do whatever you want with v2:
     'If v2.ImageID = .... Then
Next
```

Comment: You should change the definition of the KeyValuePair in the loop to `(Of Integer, ConvensionImages)`

Answer (score 21):

You can loop this way, too:

```
For Each iKey As Integer In ImageCollection.Keys
    Dim value As ConvensionImages = ImageCollection(iKey)
    '...
Next
```

It is very fast and simple way to it.

Comment: It may not be so fast. Inside the loop your are searching for the key in the dictionary for every iteration.
You should use something like `for each pair in ImageCollection` and use `pair.Value` inside the loop

Comment: that is done on the other answer, this is to provide an alternative.

Comment: If you consider @Emanuele Benedetti's comment, also consider: "Retrieving a value by using its key is very fast, close to O(1), because the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> class is implemented as a hash table." [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0)