# Is this an incorrect way of iterating over a dictionary?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Are there any problems with iterating over a dictionary in the following manner?

```vb
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"One", 1}, {"Two", 2}, {"Three", 3}}
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
   Dim Key = dict.Keys(i)
   Dim Value = dict.Item(Key)
   'Do more work
   dict.Item(Key) = NewValue
Next
```

I have used it a lot without any problems. But I recently read that the best way to iterate over a dictionary was using a `ForEach` loop. This led me to question the method that I've used.

**Update:** Note I am not asking how to iterate over a dictionary, but rather if the method that I've used successfully in the past is wrong and if so why.

Comment: So what did your research provide you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can iterate in Dictionary in vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628917/how-can-iterate-in-dictionary-in-vb-net)

Comment: I didn't find anything saying that it was wrong. But because i have used it 100's of times in my code, i would rather keep it if it's not a problem.

Comment: Let me put it another way ... have you actually seen in any tutorial them iterating a loop your way instead of using for each and key value pairs? If you keep other languages in mind many of them must iterate a dictionary/map as pairs, or via a POSITION structure.

Comment: My question is not so much how to iterate over a dictionary but rather if there are any problems with my method ... No i don't recall seeing it in tutorials but if you know that it is wrong and why, please answer the question and i will accept it.

Comment: Why a dictionary and not a list? Since you want to access by index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any problems with iterating over a dictionary in the following manner?

Yes and no. Technically there's nothing inherently wrong with the way you're doing it as it does what you need it to do, ***BUT*** it requires unnecessary computations and is therefore slower than simply using a `For Each` loop and iterating the key/value-pairs.

### Iterating keys, then fetching value

The `Keys` property is not a separate collection of keys, but is actually just a thin wrapper around the dictionary itself which contains an enumerator for *enumerating* the keys only. For this reason it also doesn't have an indexer that lets you access the key at a specific index like you are right now.

What's actually happening is that VB.NET is utilizing the extension method [`ElementAtOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault), which works by stepping through the enumeration until the wanted index has been reached. This means that for every iteration of your main loop, `ElementAtOrDefault()` also performs a similar step-through iteration until it gets to the index you've specified. You now have two loops, resulting in an *O(N * N) = O(N<sup>2</sup>)* operation.

What's more, when you access the value via `Item(Key)` it has to calculate the hash of the key and determine the respective value to fetch. While this operation is close to *O(1)*, it's still an unnecessary additional operation compared to what I'm talking about below.

### Iterating key/value-pairs

The dictionary already has an internal list (array) holding the keys and their respective values, so when iterating the dictionary using a `For Each` loop all it does is fetch each pair and put them into a `KeyValuePair`. Since it is fetching directly by index this time (at a specific memory location) you only have one loop, thus the fetch operation is *O(1)*, making your entire loop *O(N * 1) = O(N)*.

Based on this we see that iterating the key/value-pairs is actually faster.

This kind of loop would look like (where `kvp` is a `KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)`):

```
For Each kvp In dict
    Dim Key = kvp.Key
    Dim Value = kvp.Value
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand from the above that it is safe, i.e. there is no risk that the Keys property would return a different order of elements each time. Am I correct?

Comment: @Joseph : No, because the dictionary may re-order its items at any time (so the same applies for the key/value-pair loop). The `Dictionary` doesn't retain order because it doesn't have to. It was built to provide efficient hash-based lookup, which may or may not require re-ordering of the internal list.

Comment: That is interesting, thanks. I will need to think about a safe method to accomplish this...

Comment: @Joseph : If you're looking to retain the order of the items there is the [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary), but sadly it doesn't implement generics so you can't rely on strongly-typed items. There's also the [`SortedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) which sorts the items by key.

Comment: @Joseph : Note that by wanting to retain a certain order of the items you're going to lose some of the performance that a normal `Dictionary` gives you. May I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: I am not necessary looking to retain the order that they were added in. But rather i don't want the first iteration and the nth iteration to operate on the same key. This would happen if `dict.Keys` does not guarantee a consistent order within the loop. The result is that some keys will be called multiple times, other not called at all. I hope i am making myself clear...

Comment: @Joseph : Oh, well in that sense: **Yes, it is completely safe**. Any loop like this will iterate every key **exactly once**. You don't need to worry about missing or getting duplicate keys (with the exception if an error occurs in your code inside the loop, as then it will exit prematurely).

Comment: It should also be noted that if you are iterating the dictionary using `For Each`, then you'll get a hard error if someone tries to modify it while you're iterating it, which is not the case with the index-based iteration in the question.

Comment: @Craig : Yep. Considered mentioning it, but didn't :). Though the index-based loop can fail as well if items are removed, making the loop go out of bounds. In the end it just boils down to: _Don't modify your collection while iterating it_.

Answer (score 1):

See here:

https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet

> Keys. You can get a List of the Dictionary keys. Dictionary has a get accessor property with the identifier Keys. You can pass the Keys to a List constructor to obtain a List of the keys.

It cites an example similar to yours:

```vb
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Put four keys and values in the Dictionary.
        Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        dictionary.Add("please", 12)
        dictionary.Add("help", 11)
        dictionary.Add("poor", 10)
        dictionary.Add("people", -11)

        ' Put keys into List Of String.
        Dim list As New List(Of String)(dictionary.Keys)

        ' Loop over each string.
        Dim str As String
        For Each str In list
            ' Print string and also Item(string), which is the value.
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", str, dictionary.Item(str))
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: While this is better than what the OP is currently doing, putting the keys in a list results in additional operations compared to simply iterating the `Keys` collection directly (it also doesn't make sense to have them in a list if all you're doing is iterating them, so I don't understand why the tutorial does this). This is because in order to put the keys into the list the framework first has to iterate the entire collection, only for the exact same set to be iterated _again_ by the `For Each str` loop.

Comment: This results in close to a _O(2N)_ operation, whereas iterating the `Keys` directly results in close to a _O(N)_ operation.

Comment: @VisualVincent I don't offer this answer as good or bad. I simply state that there are web pages that show it can be done that way. I wouldn't use it. It is why I upvoted your answer.

Comment: I understood that you didn't, but I reacted to the tutorial's odd example of putting it in a list since it (while being faster than the OP's method) requires more memory as it's duplicating the data for no reason :). My comments kind of also serve as an extension to my answer as you introduced a third way of iterating the dictionary. I thought it'd be interesting to know the differences between everything that's been mentioned so far.